# swiftui list for each cannot display the items in each array

Tags: arrays, list, swiftui, foreach

im working on a project and i need to display some arguments from a custom view from a array in a list. But i get this error: Instance method 'appendInterpolation(_:formatter:)' requires that '[Int]' inherit from 'NSObject'.

Here is my code. I hope somebody can help me:

```
class vm: ObservableObject {
   @Published var filteredArray: [StudentView] = []

   init() {
      getusers()
   }

   func getUsers() {
      let user1 = StudentView(countall: {}, name: "Nick", averages: 0.00, grades: [1, 2, 
      2, 5, 6], getsheet: {})
      let user2 = StudentView(countall: {}, name: "Tim", averages: 0.00, grades: [1, 2, 
      2, 5, 2], getsheet: {})
   }
}


List {
   ForEach(vm.filteredArray) { studentgrade in
      Text("\(studentgrade.grade)")
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems you try to print an array of int : student.grade.grade : what is the type ?

Comment: the type of the array is a int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you need display you should use other struct with `view Protocol`

*I writed for you*

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: vm
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(viewModel.filteredArray) { student in
            HStack{
                ForEach(student.grades, id: \.self){ grade in
                    Text("\(grade)")
                }
              }                                
           }            
       }
   }
}
```

Text structure does not directly display the array. You have to use *`ForEach`* again in *`HStack`* to print the grade array side by side

Comment: thank you, i think that will definetly help me :)

Comment: could you click correct answer

Comment: yeah sorry this is my second question here